# Tourist visa to Madagascar from Canada

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, madagascar

A friend and I are traveling to Madagascar in November. We're wondering if we need to apply for tourist visas before we go, or whether we can get them at the airport. We’ll be there less than 30 days. We’re traveling on Canadian passports.

Comment: You can get a visa on arrival.. however, your own [government recommends](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/madagascar) that you obtain one in advance, along with other precautions  in its travel advisory.

Answer (score 4):

As Canadian citizens, you are not required to arrive with a visa for stays of up to 90 days since you can obtain such a visa at the airport.

You can however apply in advance which will speed up the process at the airport since you will not have to apply there and wait for processing time.

In either case, you must have a passport valid for 6 months after your date of arrival in Madagascar.

Later this year, before October, you will be able to apply electronically for a visa to Madagascar. The [official page is here](http://www.evisamada.gov.mg/en_US/page/homepage) and says that you only need apply before 3 days earlier than your trip.